# compare 2 arrays and return the index of an array when there is a match

Tags: arrays, powershell, indexing, compare

I have two arrays.  One that is an import from a CSV and the second is a list of items and id numbers.  My goal is to compare one of the columns in the CSV to the second array.  When it finds a match, i would like it to return the index of the second array so i can insert the items ID number in future lines of code.

I have tried to use .IndexOf but since i am comparing it to another array, it does not find the value.  The values of "NewPhaseName" can be different when the program runs and the NewPhaseNumber is generated during runtime as well. My script currently takes a CSV file, searches for UniquePhaseNames, sends those names through an API to generate a NewPhaseNumber.  I then need to use that NewPhaseNumber later in my script for another API call.

```
$NewPhaseName = "Plan", "Test", "Deploy"
$NewPhaseNumber = "1077", "1089", "1100"

$Ticket.PhaseDescription[1] = "Plan"
$Ticket.PhaseDescription[2] = "Plan"
$Ticket.PhaseDescription[3] = "Deploy"

$PhaseIndex = $Ticket.PhaseDescription.IndexOf($NewPhaseName)
$NewPhaseIndex = $NewPhaseNumber[$PhaseIndex]
```

What i am hoping to get would be

```
$NewPhaseIndex[0] = 1077
$NewPhaseIndex[1] = 1077
$NewPhaseIndex[2] = 1100
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to reorganize your data structure, or build a hash table from

```
$NewPhaseName = "Plan", "Test", "Deploy"
$NewPhaseNumber = "1077", "1089", "1100"

$hash = @{}
for($i=0;$i -lt $newPhaseName.Count; $i++){
  $hash[$NewPhaseName[$i]]=$NewPhaseNumber[$i]
}
$hash
```

yielding:

```
> $hash
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Plan                           1077
Deploy                         1100
Test                           1089
```

---

```
# simulate Ticket array
$Ticket = @"
PhaseDescription
"Plan"
"Plan"
"Deploy"
"@ -split '\r?\n' | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Append new column with NewPhaseIndex looked up from $hash
$Ticket | Select-Object *,@{n='NewPhaseIndex';e={$hash[$PhaseDescriptiom]}}
```

---

```
PhaseDescription NewPhaseIndex
---------------- -------------
Plan             1077
Plan             1077
Deploy           1100
```

Comment: thank you very much.  I was able to use the hash table as you suggested to fix my issue :)